# Create media library feed

Tags: media-library, feed

How can I create a xml feed for the media library? That is, a feed that will be updated each time a new file is uploaded to the media library.

Comment: I've revised your question a bit - I'm assuming you mean XML feel and not an archive, like a blog. Feel free to revise your question if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question appears to be about an xml feed for library images, the process to display those images on a page requires use of a template with a special query to look for 'attachment' type pages, which is how images are stored in the database.

That's a bit more complicated, but I did something similar in my 'Multisite Media Display' plugin, which uses a shortcode to display media images on a post/page. Works on single and multisite sites. Plugin is here https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-media-display/ .

Since plugins are open-source, you are welcome to dig into my code to see how it's done.

Comment: Your plugin looks cool (although https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/ probably has most if not all of its features, plus it supports taxonomies)! But as mentioned in a comment, I was referring to XML feeds.